# assign all values (with the same value) a std:array: brace vs .fill, what's the differences?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

If I need to [assign to an array the same values on all values](https://godbolt.org/z/oM61oPYe6), what's the differences between brace assign and .fill?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 4> array;

    array[3] = 2;
    array = {0};
    std::cout << array[3] << std::endl;

    array[3] = 2;
    array.fill(0);
    std::cout << array[3] << std::endl;
}
```

They looks the same...

Comment: Can you brace init `array` all to `1`?

Comment: @康桓瑋 oh right, {1} seems do nothing on last value. I think it will just init the value you indicate (i.e. first in this case), than fill 0 by default?

Comment: `array = {0};` creates a temporary array providing `0` value for the first item while the rest are zero-initialized.

Comment: @all got it. If you reply, I'll accept the answer :)

Comment: also can do `std::array<int, 4> array {};` or `std::array<int, 4> array{0}` which you should do instead of expecting it be initialized because `std::array` is an aggregate. It doesn't initialize itself because there is no user-defined constructor. Brace initialization is aggregate initialization for this type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `std::array<int, 4> array`:

- `array = {0}` -> `0,0,0,0`
- `array = {2}` -> `2,0,0,0`
- `array = {2,4}` -> `2,4,0,0`
- `array = {2,4,27,-3}` -> `2,4,27,-3`
- `array = {2,4,27,-3,1}` -> compile error

EDIT: Finally found a proper reference (perhaps I'm blind, but I cannot find it on cppreference.com):

From [the C++26 working draft](https://eel.is/c++draft/):

> #### 9.4.2 Aggregates [[dcl.init.aggr](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr)]
>
> 3 When an aggregate is initialized by an initializer list as specified
> in 9.4.5, the elements of the initializer list are taken as
> initializers for the elements of the aggregate. The explicitly
> initialized elements of the aggregate are determined as follows:
>
> —(3.1) If the initializer list is a brace-enclosed
> designated-initializer-list, the aggregate shall be of class type, the
> identifier in each designator shall name a direct non-static data
> member of the class, and the explicitly initialized elements of the
> aggregate are the elements that are, or contain, those members.
>
> —(3.2) **If the initializer list is a brace-enclosed initializer-list,
> the explicitly initialized elements of the aggregate are the first n
> elements of the aggregate, where n is the number of elements in the
> initializer list.**
>
> —(3.3) Otherwise, the initializer list must be {}, and there are no
> explicitly initialized elements.

> 5 For a non-union aggregate, each element that is not an explicitly
> initialized element is initialized as follows:
>
> —(5.1) If the element has a default member initializer (11.4), the
> element is initialized from that initializer.
>
> —(5.2) **Otherwise, if the element is not a reference, the element is
> copy-initialized from an empty initializer list (9.4.5).**
>
> —(5.3) Otherwise, the program is ill-formed.

> #### 9.4.5 List-initialization [[dcl.init.list](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list)]
>
> [...]
>
> (3.11) **Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements, the object
> is value-initialized.**

I think that is all the relevant parts for this question (but I am not used to reading the standard directly so corrections are welcome).